# Force using implicit cast in assign opertor

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

In following code is there any way to force on compiler using implicit cast to bool (in `b3 = b2` assignment) instead of generating copy assignment operator **without using cast operator**? Unfortunately after explicit deleting copy assignment code does not build. Lack of explicit casting is important for my framework.

```cpp
class Base
{
public :

   Base& operator=(const Base&) = delete;
   virtual Base& operator=(bool state) { state_ = state; }
   virtual operator bool() const { return state_; }
   virtual bool operator!() const { return !state_; }

protected :
   bool state_;
};

int main(void)
{
   Base b1, b2, b3;
   b1 = true;
   b2 = !b1;
   b3 = b2;

   return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**:
Error is

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:20:9: error: use of deleted function ‘Base& Base::operator=(const Base&)’
    b3 = b2;
         ^~
test.cpp:6:10: note: declared here
    Base& operator=(const Base&) = delete;
          ^~~~~~~~
```

**UPDATE2**:
As @serge-ballesta said base assignment operator is sufficient

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public :

   virtual Base& operator=(const Base &rhs) { std::cout << "BASE = BASE" << std::endl; return *this = static_cast<bool>(rhs); };
   virtual Base& operator=(bool state) { std::cout << "BASE = bool" << std::endl;  state_ = state; return *this; }
   virtual operator bool() const { return state_; }
   virtual bool operator!() const { return !state_; }

protected :
   bool state_;
};

class Derived :
   public Base
{
public :
   virtual Base& operator=(bool state) { std::cout << "DERIVED = bool" << std::endl; state_ = state; /* And something more */ return *this; }
};

int main(void)
{
   Base b1, b2, b3;
   b1 = true;
   b2 = !b1;
   b3 = b2;

   Derived d1, d2, d3, d4;
   d1 = true;
   d2 = !d1;
   d3 = d2;
   d4 = b3;

   return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

```
BASE = bool      # b1 = true;
BASE = bool      # b2 = !b1;

BASE = BASE      # b3 = b2;
BASE = bool      # ditto

DERIVED = bool   # d1 = true;
DERIVED = bool   # d2 = !d1;

BASE = BASE      # d3 = d2;
DERIVED = bool   # ditto

DERIVED = bool   # d4 = b3;
```

Interestingly in last case the implicit casting was done as I wanted to.

Comment: I'm not sure the compiler will ever try to do this without an explicit cast... there could be any number of such conversions through multiple different types.

Comment: if you explicitly delete the function, then no, you cannot do this and the error will stay.

Comment: By definition you cannot force the compiler to use an implicit cast. A cast is always explicit: it's something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. The term you're looking for is **implicit conversion**.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes, this sentence is unfortunate - I meant to guide compiler using implicit cast -> operator with casted value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitely deleting the assign operator means that you want the class to be non copyable. Here, you just want the copy assignment to use a bool conversion:

```
Base& operator=(const Base& other) {
    *this = static_cast<bool>(other);
    return *this;
}
```

Unfortunately, you will have to override the assignment operator in derived classes to force the use of this one:

```
class Derived: public Base {
public:
    Derived& operator=(Derived& other) {
        Base::operator = (other);
        return *this;
    }   
    ...
};
```

Comment: The problem is that for every derived class from `Base` I need to define this function again...

Comment: Ok I think you are right, I will tell more in update

Comment: @cdhowie: Unfortunately, even with virtual operators, the default assignment operator of the class has higher precedence unless it is overriden. In my tests additional fields in a derived  class are copied unless I override the assignment operator.

Comment: I made some tests (see update) and virtual operator=(Base &) is sufficient, no need to create new one, the question is how portable this solution is...

Comment: @Nabuchodonozor: I did my test with a rather old version of CLang. Maybe a C++ version level problem...

Comment: @SergeBallesta g++ 7.5.0 and clang++ 6.0.0 gives the same result